# How to automatically turnoff wifi immediately when charger is unplugged?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, battery, power

I have a laptop with battery that doesn't keep my laptop turned on if charger is unplugged for 3-5 minutes. I've noticed that if Wifi is disabled it can withstand to stay for 30-70 minutes.

Although I've set *Maximum Power Saving* option for *Wirless Adapter* in *Power Options* (shown below), the battery can't withstand longer than 3-5 minutes while not turning off wifi.
[image]

So I need to know how to automatically turnoff wifi immediately when charger is unplugged?

Comment: In windows i known no way, in linux you can execute commands/scripts on system events, like unplug power, but windows probably need some special tool for that. But the time difference is way too big, probably there is something running  (burning the cpu) when you have network, that stops when you disconnect. Open the task manager and check the cpu usage. Try cpuz app (or similar low level info tool) to see the cpu speed in both scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a Wireless Adapter setting. Numerous persons would not want Wireless disconnecting when they pick up a machine to move it to another location.

Make a batch file with the NETSH WLAN command, put the batch file on your desktop, run it to disconnect Wireless before unplugging.

Netsh Wlan Disconnect Interface="name of connection"

You most likely need a new battery in due course.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on John's answer, you can use Task Scheduler (`taskschd.msc`) to detect the appropriate event and the run the script automatically.